# Capture overlapping values using python regex

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have String

```
myString = "Keyword abckeyword abc blah"
```

I want to capture occurence of both keyword and value immediately following keyword until white space

```
myregex = re.compile(fr"({keyword})\s*(\S+)", re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

for m in myregex.finditer(myString):
   print(m)
```

I get result as  keyword abckeyword, but second match is not captured. How do I fix this ?

```
<_sre.SRE_Match Object; span=(0,17), match='keyword abckeyword'>
```

Expected result :

```
<_sre.SRE_Match Object; span=(0,17), match='keyword abckeyword'>
<_sre.SRE_Match Object; span=(11,21), match='keyword abc'>
```

Comment: `re.findall(rf"(?=(({keyword})\s+(\S+)))", s)` should do it.

Comment: Here, just wrap the pattern with a capturing group and place inside a positive lookahead. Note you need a word boundary before the keyword, `rf"(?=\b({keyword}\s+\S+))"`

Comment: Your desired "second match", ,`'keyword abc'` does not satisfy your requirement, "I want to capture occurrence of both keyword and value immediately following keyword until white space".